# What are the advantages of using interphase cells rather than metaphase cells for gene mapping purposes using FISH?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics

I have been told that interphase cells are better for gene mapping purposes than metaphase cells but don't know why.

Comment: Can you give more information about what kind of mapping is being done? Do you have a reference for the claim?

Comment: Clones of human DNA were used for FISH. I don't have a reference for the claim, but please could you suggest some advantages of using interphase cells rather than metaphase cells for gene mapping.

Comment: Already good to know the question is about FISH. You should edit this info in your question. Have you read the [wikipedia on FISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_in_situ_hybridization)? There seems to have quite a bit of info already that may well help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The wiki page describes the process of FISH but doesn't address advantages of using interphase instead of metaphase cells.

Answer (score 1):

In metaphase, chromosomes are at their highest level of condensation. FISH relies on being able to dissociate the two strands of DNA to anneal a sequence-specific probe. So, my guess is that it is technically easier to achieve a good FISH staining in interphase, when chromosomes are much less densely condensed. There might be other reasons I am not aware of (I am not a geneticist).